# Windows Automatic Repair Doesn't Recognise Macbook Keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, macbook, boot-camp

I've installed Windows 10 using Bootcamp to my Late Macbook 2008. After an update blue screen occurred (inaccessible boot device) and there are two options on the following screen: Restart or Advanced Options. However, a built-in keyboard and external USB keyboards don't seem to work. Is there any solution?

Comment: Did you install the MAC drivers for W10?

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting and reconnecting the USB devices?

Comment: @Moab yes, everything was done and working until the update.

Comment: @computercarguy nothing was&is connected to.

Comment: You mentioned a USB keyboard, and I assume you're also using an external mouse, which are USB devices. There's a very small, unlikely chance these caused the issue. I try never leave out the "very small, unlikely chances", due to running into them fairly often.

Comment: @computercarguy after blue screen error, the built-in keyboard didn't work and I plugged in external one to check if it is working. However, it didn't work. I've never tried a USB mouse. I don't remember if any mouse connected before the update. Does it help if I plug any? :)

Comment: There's a change it'll bypass the non-working internal versions, but I was asking more about if it wasn't working only after the update. Ya know, the old "have you tried turning it off and on again", but for peripherals. It looks like this isn't part of the problem and not likely part of the solution, either. It wouldn't hurt to try an external mouse, but doubtful if it'll accomplish anything at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how BootCamp affects things, but I'd suggest making a boot repair disk and running standard Windows repair methods. These are some of things I did when I was a PC repair tech, rather than a Mac repair tech. I don't remember the full list, since it was really long and it's been several years since I've worked as a tech.

> https://www.howtogeek.com/131907/how-to-create-and-use-a-recovery-drive-or-system-repair-disc-in-windows-8/
>
> https://www.groovypost.com/howto/fix-windows-10-wont-boot-startup-repair-bootrec/
>
> https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/how-to-fix-disk-errors-in-windows-10/

1. Boot to Win Recovery Disk/USB
2. Run the automated Startup Repair
3. Rebuild the MBR (Master Boot Record)
4. Run CHKDSK

There's a couple other things the links suggest, but I haven't done them myself.  You may need to run these steps 2-3 time for it to fully work.

There's plenty of other resources to look up repairs online. Even when I was a tech, I'd spend hours to research new fixes so I didn't have to spend days reinstalling everything. I've seen more complete repair walk throughs on SE/SO, as well as Google, so just keep searching.

If it still doesn't fix things, you can reinstall Windows. You'll want to back up your data first, though, if you haven't already done so. You can also reinstall Windows without removing the partition, but sometimes that doesn't work and you'll probably still have to reinstall all your software.

Good luck!